# What are the names of the directional or navigation keys in g1ant robot?

Tags: g1ant

I want to use directional keys of the keyboard to move the cursor in notepad but I don't know the conventional names of these keys.
For example using the enter key I can write: `keyboard ⋘enter⋙`.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and is it not in the docs? I'd try left, right, top, bottom if you haven't already.

Comment: yes, you were right. Left, right, up and down keywords work for navigating in notepad.

Comment: Cool, glad that works